# Is a visa required to re-check bags at El Alto Airport, Bolivia?

Tags: us-citizens, transit-visas, bolivia

We are US citizens flying from the United States to Peru, with a layover and plane change in El Alto Airport, Bolivia.

We do not intend to leave El Alto Airport at all. The airlines for the two segments are different, requiring us to claim and re-check our baggage. We are assuming we will have to clear customs in order to do this. Unfortunately there is a hefty visa fee to Bolivia, so we would like to verify our understanding.

Will we need a visa in order to claim our bags, re-checking them on to our connecting flight?

Comment: Are you certain they cannot tag it I2I? This is usually what is done in such cases.

Comment: Are these flights on a single booking or separate bookings?

Comment: They are on a single booking.  I'm not familiar with "I2I" and google hasn't produced any results -- what is it?

Comment: Just *what* is your itinerary, and who the *heck* are you flying it with?!  The routing through El Alto baffles me...because the major international airports in Peru all have direct service from major US international airports!

Comment: Also, an I2I tag is probably a reference to interlining the baggage between the two airlines.

Answer (score 1):

Since reclaiming and rechecking the luggage requires you to go through immigration, you will need a Bolivian visa to do so. The visa costs $160 and requires you to show a hotel reservation.